# Iterating growing table

Tags: postgresql

Is there any kind of loop in postgreSQL that allow iteration over table that has new records inserted during that loop?

```
FOR row IN (SELECT *
              FROM foo  
                   )                
LOOP
   /*
   do some actions
   */

   INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (boo) -- I want this new record to be processed in any next interation of this loop

END LOOP;
```

Comment: This looks like you don't need a loop. But first please tell us what you are planning to do exactly.

Comment: I'm using postigs. I have table of roads, and I want to split road into 2 new roads in this table, when it's intersecting with any road from some another table. New inserted row can also intersects so I want to repeat the process until none of the roads from base table will be intersecting

Comment: What happens with the original road? This has to be updated?

Comment: original road will be deleted

Comment: Maybe you can do something with `WITH RECURSIVE` and a `DELETE FROM ... RETURNING ...` but it's hard to say without your schema.